# Need a minimal Django file download example

Tags: django, file, download

I'm facing difficulty to download (the already uploaded) files as I am a newbie in django. Also I could not find a way to do that (the uploaded files are of different formats). May someone post a minimal but complete (Model, View, Template) example code to do so?

Comment: It would have been faster to search the net for "minimal Django file download example" than post a question here.

Comment: @dokaspar I could not find anything in my query. Can you please suggest me a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you alredy have model like:

```
class MyFile(models.Model):
    file_field = models.FileField()
```

1. In your view add your uploaded file in template context like:

   {'myfile': MyFile.objects.get(id=1)}
2. In your template just use `<a>` tag with:

   href="{{ myfile.file_field.url }}"